# How to make my custom `$<-` method honor `invisible()`

Tags: r, generics

I am documenting my research in `rmarkdown` workbooks but want to also save my ggplots into a variable to reconfigure the plots for other cases, for example resize them for presentations.

First, I had a function that prints my plot and saves into a global variable:

```r
PLOTS <- list()
`%<p%` <- function(name, ggplot){
  PLOTS[[name]] <<- ggplot
  print(ggplot)
  return(invisible(NULL)) # better use ggplot here (if used with %>but this is easier for question
}

# Plots and saves
"testplot" %<p% qplot(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, data = iris)
```

Soon I had the problem that I want to save one version of the plot, but plot another version, for example save the plot but then plot in my workbook two versions with different x axis limits. So I introduced that the function recognizes `invisible()`:

```r
`%<p%`<- function(name, ggplot){
  v <- withVisible(ggplot)$visible
  if(v) print(ggplot)
  PLOTS[[name]] <<- ggplot
  return(invisible(NULL)) 
}

# Save full plot but print only x between 4 and 5
"testplot" %<p% invisible(qplot(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, data = iris))
PLOTS$testplot + coord_cartesian(xlim = c(4,5))
```

Works beautifully. Then I got really lazy and wanted to use the RStudio shortcut for `<-` instead of typing unwieldy special characters for `%<p%`, so I thought of making this function an implementation of the `$<-` generic, for a new class "plotlist". I then create a list with this new class to cause invokation of  `` `$<-.plotlist`() `` when an element is assigned to this.

```r
PLOTS2 <- structure(list(), class = "plotlist")
`$<-.plotlist` <- function(x, name, value){
  v <- withVisible(value)$visible
  if(v) print(value)
  NextMethod()
}
```

But now things get strange as now the `invisible()` does not work anymore. For example, this renders the ggplot:

```r
PLOTS2$test <- invisible(qplot(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, data = iris))
```

On the other hand, if I hadn't used the custom `$<-` implementation, it wouldn't even print by default, for example if I use my ordinary list without the special class "plotlist" to store my plot!

```r
PLOTS$test <- qplot(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, data = iris)
```

How is this? I do not really know how `invisible()` works and the manuals of `invisible()` and `withVisibility()` say only the object stays invisible "for a while". What are the criteria how long is an object invisible, why is it not in my custom `$<-` implementation and can I make it honor `invisible()`?

Comment: It's not clear why you would need a specific method here, when you can assign the plot to a normal list without it printing. `invisible` is really used for returning from a function, not interactive use. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: My main objective is to get a better understanding about what `invisible()` is, having found that `invisible()` works for a normal function but doesn't work for a custom `$<-.x()`. It seems to be a different breed than for example attributes and classes and I hope to understand the foundations of the R language better with it. Maybe the question is more academic, but from time to time, knowledge that I deemed academic before payed off in practice at some point.

Comment: `invisible` is used when you want a function to return without it printing to the console. This already happens if you assign the output of a function. If you want the function to run because of its side effects (such as drawing a plot or assigning to a global variable), you would tend to use `invisible(NULL)` at the end. Or, if your function outputs a monstrous data object that should not be printed to the console, you might return it invisibly. There's not much more to it than that.